# Vertically and Horizontally Center CSS Background Image Sprite

Tags: css, background-image

Without extra markup, how can I add a background image to a `div` of a certain height and width (pulled from a sprite [multiple images put together]) while centering it vertically and horizontally? It's cake when it's a single image:

HTML:

```html
<div id="blog">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#blog .circle {
    background-image: url("../img/blog.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

I want to achieve the same effect using a single sprite for all of the images, while retaining the centering and defining a width and height which restrain the size of the background image.

Answer (score 3):

```
background-image: url("../img/blog.png") no-repeat center center;
```

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to have multiple images in that PNG and be able to restrain the size like with a separate element.

Comment: oh... then you probably should set your div style: `display:table-cell;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;` and put those sprites as separate images inside the div.

Comment: Your answer should be entirely in your post, not down here in comments.

Comment: not sure if you should be commenting 8 years old posts

Answer (score 2):

You should set the margin of the circle div to auto.

```
#blog .circle {
    margin:auto auto; background-image: url("../img/blog.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin to auto but also set the image width and height.

Example:

```
.btn_arrow_right {
    background: url("../img/arrow_right.png") 0px -33px no-repeat;
    width: 19px;
    height: 33px;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```